# TCPDF Overlapping Tables

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I just started working with a new web app in Symfony, which one of it's functions is to print receipts using TCPDF. It works fine, but every once in a while when a client wants to put one of the field really big(in this case the Observation field), it overlaps with other tables, like the following image:

[image: Receipt screenshot]

I tried to cut as much of the code as possible to show you and not be so confused.

But the most relevant piece of code (I think) is this one:

```
if($showObservacoesProdutos){
                if($value->getObservacoes() != ''){
                    //ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!! IT'S HERE THAT'S OVERLAPPING WITH EVERYTHING!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
                    $htmlProdutos[$count] .= '
                        <tr '.$line.'>
                            <td colspan="7" style="text-align: justify; font-size: 22px;"><b>'.__("Observações").':</b> '.nl2br($value->getObservacoes()).'</td>
                        </tr>';
                }
            }

            $htmlProdutos[$count] .= '</table>';

            $flag++;

            ($key+1 == sizeof($this->produtos)) ? $height=187 : $height=259;

            if($documento instanceof CmrFacturas && $key+1 == sizeof($this->produtos)){
                if($sf_user->getAttribute('id_pais_empresa') == InfPaises::ID_PORTUGAL){
                    $htmlProdutos[$count] .='<div style="padding-top: 5px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">'.__("Os artigos / serviços foram colocados à disposição do adquirente na data").' '.$documento->getDataEmissao().'. ('.__("Alínea F nº5 artº 36 CIVA").').</div>';
                }                    
            }

            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(190, '', '', $pdf->getY(), $htmlProdutos[$count], 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);

            $pdf->Ln();

            if($pdf->getY() > $height){
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $count++;
                $flag = 0;
            }
```

Since this is in Portuguese, the field that is overlapping is called `Observações`.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

EDIT: With spaces, the problem doesn't look so serious. I think now the only problem is that it is overlapping with the header. I also traded the image above to correspond with a receipt with spaces.

EDIT2: I got an idea but no idea on how to execute it. Maybe the problems lies within the html disposition. Instead of putting the `Observações` part in a cell inside a table, maybe I can put it inside another html container, except I already tried using `divs` and `p`, but it still overlaps. Maybe somebody else has another idea.

EDIT3: If I reduce the size of the text of the `Observações` part, it stops overlapping, but if I inscrese the number of lines in one of the products, it starts to overlap again.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to add the relevant piece of code into the question? We want questions here to be useful for posterity, but it is our experience that pasteboards and image hosts do not always let links last for very long.

Comment: You are right. Like I said, I'm fairly new to this library so I don't know if what I put in the question is really that relevant or not :/

Comment: I wonder if there is a word wrapping issue that is interacting with it. Try putting spaces in the large data to see if that helps - HTML doesn't do very well if it can't wrap lines at clean break points.

Comment: With spaces, the problem doesn't look so serious. I think now the only problem is that it is overlapping with the header

Comment: NOTE: I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but I'm using inline CSS, so I don't know if that afects anything or not...

Comment: @halfer I just posted some edits from testing, maybe it can help from getting an idea :p

Comment: Does setting an explicit line or cell height in CSS help? I've only used TCPDF a bit, so I'd just be guessing at this point.

Comment: I tried, but since the `Observações` field is dynamically inserted, I can't put a defined cell height